# removing cookies using javascript is not done immediatly

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am currently working with a javascript that is supposed to remove some unwanted cookies, but for some reason aren't they removed when told to?.. 
only after certain amount of times trying to remove them, they seem to be removed.. some sort of delayed effect?

here is the code:

```
 const name = 'test_u';
 const name1 = 'test_te_s';

 function eraseCookie(name) {   
     document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
 }

function removeCookies(cookieA, cookieB) {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (document.cookie.includes(cookieA) || document.cookie.includes(cookieB)) 
        {
            eraseCookie(cookieA);
            eraseCookie(cookieB);
            var date = new Date();
            var timestamp = date.getTime();
            console.log(timestamp)
        }
    },10000);
}

removeCookies(name, name1);
```

example from console log output:

```
1555420706478
1555420716477
1555420726487
1555420736487
1555420746497
1555420756487
```

It runs 6 times before its removed? but why though?

why aren't they removed immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `setInterval` which means that that code will be run after some time that you provide, and keep repeating it by that interval. So just remove that `setInterval`:

```
function removeCookies(cookieA, cookieB) {
    if (document.cookie.includes(cookieA) || document.cookie.includes(cookieB)) {
        eraseCookie(cookieA);
        eraseCookie(cookieB);
        var date = new Date();
        var timestamp = date.getTime();
        console.log(timestamp)
    }
}
```

And if you want to keep repeating it try this one:

```
removeCookies(name, name1);
setInterval(() => {
    removeCookies(name, name1);
}, 10000);
```

or

```
function removeCookies(cookieA, cookieB) {
    if (document.cookie.includes(cookieA) || document.cookie.includes(cookieB)) {
        eraseCookie(cookieA);
        eraseCookie(cookieB);
        var date = new Date();
        var timestamp = date.getTime();
        console.log(timestamp)
    }

    setInterval(() => {
        removeCookies()
    }, 10000);
}
removeCookies(name, name1);
```

so it will first call removeCookies, and then it will keep repeating.

Comment: how do i retrigger it, when it reappears?

Comment: @IamnotFat you just call `removeCookies()` again

Comment: @IamnotFat i'm just seeing it now. why `eraseCookie` function is not really erasing the cookie but its setting. Which means that `removeCookies` function its not removing `cookies` at all, but setting two of them

Comment: As I understand that is the way to delete the cookie, by changing the expire date to some something expired, but i need somehow to detect if it is being reset from outside, meaning that i should retrigger the condition whether the document contains the unwanted cookies, and then remove them if they are. 

but if i remove  setInterval, this will not be retriggered.. so how do i retrigger it?

Comment: @IamnotFat sorry i missed the `-` in max-age. Anyway i just updated the answer, so now you can run it immediately and then it will keep repeating

Comment: but again, this goes back to my prior point, this solution does not seem to work, as the cookie does not seem to be deleted after `eraseCookie()`has been executed, the function is being executed multiple times, and then gets removed..